# Interpretation of expected wealth in Kelly betting paper

Tags: optimization, expected-value

*This is a sub-question of [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926829/how-to-write-probability-that-result-of-objective-function-is-lower-than-y-in).*

[Kelly betting on horse races with uncertainty
in probability estimates (Metel 2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02814.pdf) describes an "ECC" variant of the Kelly method defined as

[image: ECC method1]

with variables

- *h* the horse index, known;
- *n* the number of horses, known;
- $\pi$ a fixed-size vector of winning probabilities, known;
- *O* a fixed-size vector of payout odds, known;
- *w* current wealth, known;
- *x* a fixed-size vector of wagers, unknown, the object of optimization.

Calculating the inner expressions is easy, but I find interpreting the "expected" and "probability" outer expressions difficult. If the inner probability values are all known and fixed, isn't the probability of the wealth logarithm being less than some value either 0 or 100%?

I (and the original poster of the first question) probably need some introductory-level guidance about what these two expressions really assume about the nature of the probability vector - does this optimization only work if there are implied probability distribution functions?